# closed keg fermentation - is it taking place?

Tags: carbonation, kegging, priming-sugar

long story short - primed the keg with sugar, let it raise up to temperature, can't hear any gargling. IS my sugar carbonation taking place or all the old yeasts have died ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in theory it is. but no real way to tell, until serving time.

one way to tell is either hook up a regulator to it and get the pressure, or press the gas in valve without anything hooked up to see if its building up pressure.

Comment: any hints / procedure on properly hooking up and checking with a regulator ? thanks

Comment: On my regulator, it tells me the pressure when I hook up the gas line to the keg. My regulator is a cheapest you can get. similar to https://eckraus.com/economy-co2-regulator-double-gauge/

Comment: looks like the regulator method is not working. 3 days ago it read 1.5 bar, today it reads 0. Checked the regulator, it has not broken, it still operates.  :-|

Comment: Looks like you might have a leaky keg

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect to hear anything.  It's a closed system, the CO2 is dissolving into the beer, not bubbling to the top - as there is no pressure difference for the bubbles to "gurgle-into" (your bottles don't gurgle right!?)

It would be absolutely normal for this to work fine.  Even clear beers can have ~100 ppm of yeast cells.  So unless this beer was super-high gravity, and the yeast were at their alcohol limit, everything will be OK.  Even if it's at super high gravity, it will probably still work, just take a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any gargling. You can always pull the PRV quickly to see if there is any pressure building up... but then you are losing CO2 that isn't going to make it into the beer.

Most kegs still need a blast of CO2 to properly seat the lid.  The slow rise in pressure while naturally carbonating often isn't enough to seat and seal the lid.  At this point it is possible that your CO2 has been escaping the keg.

I assume you have a CO2 tank and regulator based on your comments on a different answer.  Looks like you're going to have to naturally carbonate anyway, so why not pull on the PRV to see if there is any pressure.  Hook up your CO2 tank and blast in 20PSI of pressure to determine if the lid seals.  Then crank it back to your intended carbonation/serving pressure, chill the keg and wait a few days before checking again.  JUST MAKE SURE THE LID IS SEALED.  Otherwise you'll just bleed out all the CO2 from your tank.

Comment: alright, thanks. It has been sitting at 1.85 bar for some days now... or maybe the regulator needs some tapping for the clock to take fresh measurement.  Anyway, pressure has only gone up, not down.

Comment: Good to hear.  Good luck

Comment: here is some news: theregulator's regulation valve has become hard to turn by hand. So hard that a wrench was needed to budge it. And the reading is still the same since last week. Any clues to that ?

Comment: The knob should be unaffected by pressure settings.  I fear your regulator is faulty.